# How can I manually cache Firestore data in SQLite database in android device using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-sqlite

I am building a Flutter app that requires me to manually cache the Firestore data into SQLite database of the android device such that whenever the device loses internet connection, it would automatically fetch data from the local storage. I've seen similar queries but none of them have any satisfactory answer.
Here is my main.dart file :

```
void main() {
   runApp(firebase_ini());
}

class firebase_ini extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseApp> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text("ERROR STARTING THE APP");
        else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
          return MaterialApp(home: pets());
        else
          return Text("LOADING...");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if any other relevant information is required.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't firestore has its own built-in cache feature? I can turn off my internet, kill the app and reopen to find everything working as it is. It even records your write operations, updates your UI accordingly, and then sends them to the database when the connection is restored. Read more here- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: It does have autocaching, but I've been assigned a task which requires me to manually store the data

Comment: You would most likely have to design your own algorithm to sync the data between firestore and local DB. If the task doesn't require you to export this DB and keep it only in the device, you could check out localstore https://pub.dev/packages/localstore